# How to work around the different behaviour of std::vector between gcc 4.7 and 4.9?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, libstdc++, std

I have something that can be compiled in gcc 4.9, but failed in gcc 4.7.

It is a class which has move constructor, but I set its copy constructor to private:

```
class Option
{
public:
    Option(const std::string& name_long,
           char               name_short,
           const std::string& group,
           bool*              value_store,
           int32_t            flags,
           const std::string& option_desc);
    // and several similar constructors

    Option(Option&& other);

private:
    Option(const Option& other);
};
```

The issue occurs when it is called by vector's `emplace_back()` function:

```
// options is a std::vector<Option>
options.emplace_back("help", 'h', OPTION_GROUP_MISC,
                     &opt_show_help, htio2::Option::FLAG_NONE,
                     "Show help and exit.");
```

This successfully compiles and works well by gcc 4.9, but gcc 4.7 claims a two-screen-long error, claiming that its copy constructor is private:

```
In file included from /public/yx/works/writing_tcrklass2/src/TCRklass2-1.90.0-Source/src/tcrk2/App.h:4:0,
                 from /public/yx/works/writing_tcrklass2/src/TCRklass2-1.90.0-Source/src/tcrk2/App.cpp:1:
......
/public/yx/works/writing_tcrklass2/src/TCRklass2-1.90.0-Source/src/tcrk2/App.cpp:58:47:   required from here
/usr/local/include/htio2/OptionParser.h:188:5: error: ‘htio2::Option::Option(const htio2::Option&)’ is private
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/move.h:57:0,
......
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/type_traits:762:43: error: within this context
```

As some of my users has very old system, which is probably using old version of compilers, I really want to know if is there any way to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you never use the copy ctor, instead of making it private, you can delete it:

```
Option(const Option&) = delete;
```

this may help the compiler to pick up the right, available ctor.

Otherwise you can try to build a temp object manually and move it back:

```
options.push_back(Option("help", 'h', OPTION_GROUP_MISC,
                         &opt_show_help, htio2::Option::FLAG_NONE,
                         "Show help and exit."));
```

Comment: *"you can delete it, [...], this may help the compiler to pick up the right, available ctor."*, deleted functions participate in the overload resolution as if they existed. if they are picked, error is raised

Comment: @PiotrS. definitely. Do you think that if it fails with `private`, it cannot succeed also with `delete`? We are talking about a bug in an old gcc version: it seems hard to predict the behaviour, I would give it one try.

Comment: I wouldn't *give it a try* if the solution is intended to be portable and conforming

Comment: @PiotrS. everything on this page is portable and conforming standard C++11, isn't it? The only non conforming things are compiler bugs, if you want or need to live with them you need to find something that they like...

Comment: access control is the last step, when the best viable overload was already selected. making the constructor deleted won't help and may change the semantics

Comment: @jiandingzhe for curiosity: did it work with delete or you used push_back?

Comment: @PiotrS. the problem is that GCC 4.7 didn't implement access checking as part of template argument substitution, so a private copy constructor doesn't work well with SFINAE, whereas a deleted function does work with SFINAE. So in GCC 4.7 a private function and a deleted function are not equivalent, and the `is_copy_constructible` trait gives an error for types with private copy constructors.

Answer (score 2):

g++ 4.7 wants a noexcept move constructor:

```
Option(Option&& other) noexcept {};
```

Comment: It don't work. The compiler still went to search the copy constructor.

Comment: @jiandingzhe, doing that in a very simple test worked for me, using 4.7.0, 4.7.1, 4.7.2 or 4.7.3, so you must be doing something different in your real code. In any case, even if you fixed the problem by deleting the copy constructor, it is a good idea to define your move constructors so they can't throw and to add `noexcept`.

Answer (score -2):

if you don't want to copy you could use shared_ptr.

```
class Option;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Option> OptionPtr;

OptionPtr o = boost::make_shared<Option>("help", 'h', OPTION_GROUP_MISC,
                         &opt_show_help, htio2::Option::FLAG_NONE,
                         "Show help and exit.");

std::vector<OptionsPtr> options;
options.push_back(o);
```